# Make Jumplist Shortcut Always Run Application as Administrator

Tags: windows-8, administrator, jumplist

I have Visual Studio 2010, for instance, pinned to my taskbar. I have pinned a solution to it so I can just right-click the VS icon and then choose my solution to fire it up (e.g. from the Jumplist). However, this opens VS in non-administrator mode (which can't access the IIS metabase).

So I have to open VS first and then open my solution.

I know the pinned taskbar app shortcuts are stored at `%APPDATA%\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`, but what about the files that are pinned to those shortcuts?

How can I make the solution shortcut (in Jumplist), which is pinned to the VS icon, open VS in administrator mode?

[image]

[image]

Comment: techie007: not quite - that works fine, launching the pinned SLN is what is opening VS in non-admin mode. Thanks though.

Comment: Can you just go to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" and mark it to always launch as Administrator?

Comment: @GaneshR.: I tried, but `devenv.exe` does not have a Compatibility tab.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See "Option 7" on the following page:
http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9564-run-administrator-windows-8-a.html

Using the registry, you can set the application to always run as administrator.  This solved the jump-list issue for me.

**To Set "Run as administrator" in Registry Editor**

1. In Regedit, locate the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers`.
2. Add a new String value (or edit the existing one) with the name set to the path to the executable (e.g. for VS2012: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`).
3. Set the new key's value to `~ RUNASADMIN` (see the link above for more options).

Comment: I had to add the layers key and then the value, but then it worked immediately without a restart.

Comment: This still applies to Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the whole of VS open as admin, to do so open explorer navigate to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSEnv\VsLauncher.exe
```

Right click on it and switch to the properties tab and check the always Run this program as an administrator checkbox.

[image]

Then click apply to save the setting.

Comment: I did try to do that before on `devenv.exe` but there is no compatability tab in that case. I tried what you suggested on `VSLauncher` but it still opened in non-admin mode.

Comment: oh, i use this on my PC and it works fine. You are talking about opening files from explorer and jumplists right, like clicking on the .sln file ?

Comment: @TaylorGibb Josh M. is using Windows 8. There is some changes in Windows 8 with the Compatibility tab I suppose.