# Is there a way to run the software as administrator when opening via jump list

Tags: windows-10, administrator, jumplist

I have set an .exe I use a lot (Visual Studio, but I don't feel it's relevant what program) to always run as administrator by right clicking on the icon, clicking Properties, then clicking Advanced from the Shortcut tab I can set "always run as administrator". This works as expected.

The problem is, this icon is pinned to the start bar along the bottom of the screen and such I have access to the jump list. Whenever I single click the pinned icon it opens as administrator. When ever I open a recent file from the jump list, it does not run as administrator.

Is there something I should have done differently? Why does it not run as admin?

Comment: It has been solved here: https://superuser.com/questions/482368/make-jumplist-shortcut-always-run-application-as-administrator

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017, I tweaked directions from other posts and it solved the issue.

[Windows 10: how to open application as Administrator when clicking on pinned items](https://superuser.com/questions/1011565/windows-10-how-to-open-application-as-administrator-when-clicking-on-pinned-ite)

[Can you force Visual Studio to always run as an Administrator in Windows 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257110/can-you-force-visual-studio-to-always-run-as-an-administrator-in-windows-8)

1. Right-click Visual Studio 2017 icon in the taskbar.
2. Right-click "Visual Studio 2017" and choose "Properties"
3. On the Shortcut tab, click "Open File Location"
4. Right-click `devenv.exe` and **select "Troubleshoot compatibility"**.
5. Select "Troubleshoot program"
6. Check "The program requires additional permissions"
7. Click "Next"
8. Click "Test the program..."
9. Wait for the program to launch (you might be asked to run as admin, click yes)
10. Click "Next"
11. Select "Yes, save these settings for this program"
12. Click "Close"

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, jump lists are registered to the executable *itself*, not to any particular shortcut to it.

You can hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> when clicking any taskbar or Start menu item, to run it as administrator.

Comment: Sadly, whilst that will start the program as an admin, it won't help solve the issue of opening the file and opening the program as an admin :(  And sadly, there is no option for Compatability Mode in Properties of devenv.exe (the exe for Visual Studio) to set it :(

Comment: As far as I can see, it does open my jumplist items with admin privileges.

Comment: Ah... it isn't for me... I wonder if this is due to application or similar. I'll have a play

Comment: I don't suppose you have Visual Studio do you to confirm if the issue is only with me?